# Не передается значение select методом post. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, html5, handlebars

Есть код:

```
<form method="POST" id="select">
<select name="day">
    <option disabled>День</option>
    {{#each day}}
        <option>{{this}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
<select name="month">
    <option disabled>Месяц</option>
    {{#each month}}
        <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
<select name="year">
    <option disabled>Год</option>
    {{#each year}}
        <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

Регистрация

При попытке передать эти значения на сервер, возникает ошибка:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined
```

**Помогите, пожалуйста. В чем заключается ошибка?**

Comment: _Есть код.._ Ваш код ни о чем не говорит. Это не HTML, а JS шаблон, судя по всему для Handlebars. Предоставьте результирующий HTML, к-ый вы видите на странице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее все проблема в том что вы не указываете из какого `option` брать `value`, т.е. не установлено `selected`, а если его не указывать то берётся из первого `option` у которого стоит `disabled` и нет `value`.

Просто нужно добавить `selected`

Например: `<option value="{{this}}" selected>{{this}}</option>`